# Hibernate persist() does insert than update

Tags: hibernate

Test for hibernate persist() has following output:

Hibernate: select nextval ('SEQ_wal')

Hibernate: insert into wal

Hibernate: update wal

Does anybody knows why it has update after insert? I am not updating entity after persist().